# Editing bash.bashrc file and reinstating file copy

Tags: bashrc

I want to edit my bash.bashrc file. Before I do this I know that I should make a back-up of the original file. What do I do if I make a mistake and need to use my back-up? Do I delete the corrupted file and rename my copy to bash.bashrc, or something else? I'm going to make cowsay say fortunes in terminal so this is a low priority. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's couple of options if you make mistakes :

- keep multiple copies of your personal  `.bashrc` *before*  making changes, so you don't have to undo edits.
- If something goes wrong, you can always open `.bashrc` with a graphical text editor , like gedit, and undo changes
- If you absolutely have to nuke the old bashrc, do `cp /etc/bash.bashrc $HOME/.bashrc`
- If you need to do it through terminal, launch terminal with different shell, such as `dash` which comes with Ubuntu by default , open text editor such as `vim` or `nano` and undo the changes.

Comment: when I copy the file should I name it bash.bashrc.old? I am so new I am not sure here. Your answer seems much simpler than A.B.'s answer.  As soon as I know how to handle the copying I'll give your answer a try. Allen

Comment: if you need a naming  convention  you can take .back for backup that is common  when it comes to Linux. .old is a windows relict. But there is no difference between  them  as long as the old file is known as the old one by the person that like to use it. That's you right? So you can name your file after every conventional  pattern  you like.

Comment: @AllenMershon you can make the extensions whatever you what it to be - linux doesn't care about extensions as much as Windows. I could have my backup files say `.bashrc.bak` or `.bashrc.crap` and it still would be OK. Also, I've noticed you're always saying `bash.bashrc` The `bash.bashrc` is the one in `/etc` . You do know what every user has `.bashrc` in their homefolder, right ?

Comment: I had to create the .bashrc file in my home directory in order to get this to work, but it all went well.

Comment: @AllenMershon strange, by default users should already have a `.bashrc` created automatically for them. Anyway, my main point was that they're the ones you need to play with, not `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: @Serg Got it! just learning now how to navigate the file system, yesterday and today. Using LInux for about a month now.

Comment: Awesome ! Welcome to the Linux world and to askubuntu !  Keep on asking good questions and maybe answer a few,too

Answer (score 2):

1. Perform a backup

   ```
   cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
   ```
2. Make your changes
3. Re-check the changed `.bashrc` and activate

   with

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   or simply start a new shell with

   ```
   bash
   ```
4. Test the changes
5. If you experience problems restore the `.bashrc`

   ```
   cp ~/.bashrc.bak ~/.bashrc
   ```

   A `source ~/.bashrc` isn't helpful now. You have to logout and re-login

Comment: Instead of sourcing, just run `bash` - then you can exit that shell if things go wrong.